# Generating 2nd Degree Polynomials from 3-tuples

Tags: python-2.7

The purpose of this code is to "Write a function/sub gen_2nd_deg_polys that takes a list of 3-tuples and returns a list of anonymous 2nd
degree polynomials."
    It's telling me that the "function" object has no ***Getitem*** attribute.

Am I missing something important about accessing tuples within the lambda?

```
import sys

def gen_2nd_deg_polys(coeffs):
    return lambda x: (
    str(coeffs[0][0]) + 'x^2 + ' + str(coeffs[0][1]) + 'x + ' + str(coeffs[0][2]) + ' at x = ' + str(x), coeffs[0][0] * x ** 2 + coeffs[0][1] * x + coeffs[0][2])

polys = gen_2nd_deg_polys([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])

polys[0](1)
polys[1](2)
```

Edited... still very wrong

```
def gen_2nd_deg_polys(coeffs):
    plist = []
    for coeff in coeffs:
        plist.append(lambda x, coeff=coeff:str(coeff[0]) + 'x^2 + ' + str(coeff[1]) + 'x + ' + str(coeff[2]) + ' at x = ' + str(x),  coeff[0] * x**2 + coeff[1] *x + coeff[2])
    return plist

polys = gen_2nd_deg_polys([(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
print(polys[0](1))
print(polys[1](2))
```

Comment: You are returning ONE lambda function instead of a list of lambda functions

Comment: How would I go about returning a list of lambda functions??

Comment: hint: `coeffs[0][0]` gets the coefficient of x^2 from the FIRST 3-tuple of coefficients. The same coefficient from the second 3-tuple is `coeffs[1][0]`; and thus the coefficient of x^2 in the `i`th 3-tuple is `coeffs[i][0]`. Now, try putting that logic in a for loop, and append your lambda functions  to a list

Comment: This is the attempt I've made. I'm very lost...
(It's unreadable, I'll post an edit to the original.
print(p1(1))
flist= []
for i in xrange(2):
    def gen_2nd_deg_polys(coeffs):

        def f  = lambda x: (str(coeffs[0][0]) + 'x^2 + ' + str(coeffs[0][1]) + 'x + ' + str(coeffs[0][2]) + ' at x = ' + str(x), coeffs[0][0] * x ** 2 + coeffs[0][1] * x + coeffs[0][2])
        return f
    flist.append(gen_2nd_deg_polys(i))

flist(2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of problems to solve here. Firstly, your `gen_2nd_deg_polys` function need to loop over your list of tuples and generate a `lambda` object representing a polynomial from each of them. They can be returned in a list which you can index into (using `[]`) and called (using `()`).

A subtle point is that Python binds variable references "late" in `lambda` definitions (see [e.g. here](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures) for more on this), so a simple loop like:

```
for pcoeffs in coeffs:
    plist.append(lambda x: pcoeffs[0] * x**2 + pcoeffs[1] * x + pcoeffs[2])
```

will cause all your `lambdas` to use the *last* tuple of `pcoeffs` encountered in `coeffs` (so all your polynomials will be the same). One way around this (the usual one, AFAIK) is to set `pcoeffs` as a default argument as in the following:

```
def gen_2nd_deg_polys(coeffs):
    plist = []
    for pcoeffs in coeffs:
        plist.append(lambda x, pcoeffs=pcoeffs: pcoeffs[0] * x**2 + pcoeffs[1] * x + pcoeffs[2])
    return plist

coeffs = [(1,2,3), (0,4,3), (1,5,-3)]

polys = gen_2nd_deg_polys(coeffs)

print polys[0](3), 1*9 + 2*3 + 3
print polys[1](3), 4*3+3
print polys[2](3), 1*9 + 5*3 - 3
```

Comment: This makes sense, thanks! But check my edited code. This is giving me issues by saying that the global name 'x' is not defined.

Comment: You've mangled your syntax a bit: try `plist.append(lambda x, coeff=coeff:str(coeff[0]) + 'x^2 + ' + str(coeff[1]) + 'x + ' + str(coeff[2]) + ' at x = ' + str(x) +  ' is ' + str(coeff[0] * x**2 + coeff[1] *x + coeff[2]))` so you return a single string from your `lambda`.

Comment: You're a pro. I see now that I just had some bad syntax. Thanks.